# Taylor Series Corollary

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, inverse

The property I am about to describe seems to me to naturally derived from the definition of Taylor series :

> Let $ g $ and $ f $ be two real analytic functions such that $ g (x): = f ^ {- 1} (x) $
> $$g(x_0)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{g^{\{n\}}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n \tag{1}$$
> If we choose $ x_0 $ such that the expression $ (1) $ converges in $ y_0 $ and not converge in $ g (x) $, we will have that $ | g (x) -g (x_0) |> | g (x) -y_0 | $ therefore by iterating the calculation and placing $ x_1 = f (y_0) $ in $ (1) $ instead of $ x_0 $ we will get that the expression will converge in $ y_1 $ such that $ | g (x) -y_0 |> | g (x) -y_1 | $. We will have $ y_M = g (x) $ for $ M \to \infty $.

Is this a corollary, a known property or is it a proposition that needs proof?